# Groovy : how to fetch last 3 characters of a random length text?

Tags: groovy

input :
DEPT MGR_AEG

output :
AEG

above is the input and expected output from piece of Groovy code. I mean I need to fetch the last 3 characters of input string. how to achieve this in Groovy ?

thanks in advance for your help.
reg, Avinash

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: going through the documentation 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_strings.htm'

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is a substring expression:'

```
assert 'DEPT MGR_AEG'[-3..-1] == 'AEG'
```

You can also use take() but it's somewhat unintuative:

```
assert 'DEPT MGR_AEG'.reverse().take(3).reverse() == 'AEG'
```

Comment: I didn't understand the code. can you make it even simpler please.

Comment: Time for you to read up a bit. http://grails.asia/groovy-substring

Comment: thanks ou_ryperd for referring that page. really helpful and learnt lot other stuffs. thanks again.